# Have an AND operator inside MATCHED clause of SQL Server MERGE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using the MERGE statement as follows:

```
MERGE a as TARGET
USING b as SOURCE
on (a.id = b.id)
WHEN MATCHED AND
a.field1 <> 'xyz' AND
a.field1 IS NULL OR
a.field1 <> b.field1
...
...

THEN UPDATE
...
...
```

What I am expecting is, that it works as an if else condition .i.e as soon as and **AND** fails then it exits.

In this case when one of the AND condition fails in MATCHED then update should not occur.
.i.e
if `a.field1 <> 'xyz'` fails, update should not occur.

But it does.

Is it that SQL server does not look at conditionals branch by branch?

Comment: You have an `OR` in there. `WHERE 1=2 AND 3=4 OR  5=5` is **true**. Use of parenthesis is important. We don't know what the full logic should be here, so you'll need to add them in to correct places yourself. If everything must be true, don't use `OR` use `AND`.

Comment: We especially can't help fix it since `a.field1 <> 'xyz' AND a.field1 IS NULL` will never be True.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, the logic that you want is:

```
WHEN MATCHED AND
     a.field1 <> 'xyz' AND
     (a.field1 IS NULL OR a.field1 <> b.field1)
```

Your logic is interpreted as:

```
WHEN (MATCHED AND
      a.field1 <> 'xyz' AND
      a.field1 IS NULL
     ) OR
     (a.field1 <> b.field1)
```